# Combining Database Entries Using a Key to Produce Table with One Entry per Key

Tags: sql

## What I Have

I have an sql database with several tables interrelated by integer keys.  Here are my 3 tables, the column names, and some sample data for each table.  Keep in mind that I am just typing this up to give an idea, it is not a direct copy/paste from a database (and thus the formatting is meant to convey the point, not to be readable by an sql database parser.)

Table 1

```
ItemTable
itemID,itemName, fruitOrVeggie, Color
1, Apple, Fruit, Red
2, Orange, Fruit, Orange
3, Carrot, Vegetable, Orange
```

Table 2

```
AttributeTypesTable
attributeID,attributeName
1, Price
2, Weight
3, Diameter
```

Table 3

```
ItemAttributesTable
itemID,attributeID,attributeValue
1, 1, .75
1, 2, .5
1, 3, .7
2, 1, .9
2, 3, .7
3, 1, .3
3, 2, .5
```

Note how I have multiple entries for each itemID in the ItemAttributesTable - this is the part I am trying to consolidate in a new table.

## What I Want

From these three tables I want to create a new table like this.

```
NewTable
itemID,itemName,fruitOrVeggie,Color,Price,Weight,Diameter
1, Apple, Fruit, Red, .75, .5, .7
2, Orange, Fruit, Orange, .9, , .7
3, Carrot, Vegetable, Orange, .3, .5,
```

In this NewTable, itemID is a unique key so that there is only one entry per itemID - this is the goal.  Note how each attributeName is now a column in this new table and how the corresponding data from ItemAttributesTable is now listed here with a single entry for each itemID (leaving a field blank if ItemAttributesTable doesn't have an entry for that attributeID for that itemID).  I do not want to have to hard code in the column names because my actual data has around a dozen columns and I want this query to be versatile enough to be able to keep using it even if an attributeName changes, I add or remove some of them, etc.

## How to Get There

I'm mainly looking at the sql involved for this sort of complex query, although a shell of some sort to actually create this new table might be nice.  For example, a query and then a Python script that runs that query to create the ItemAttributesTable.

The key parts are how to create a column in a new table based on an entry in another table (in this case, attributeName) and then how to properly pull the data from multiple tables to populate this new table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator for rotating a table-valued expression.[SELECT…INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) creates a new table and inserts the resulting rows from the query into it

```
IF OBJECT_ID('NewTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE NewTable
SELECT ItemID, ItemName, FruitOrVeggie, Color, Price, Weight, Diameter
INTO NewTable
FROM      
(      
 SELECT t.ItemID, t.ItemName, t.FruitOrVeggie, Color, attributeName, attributeValue
 FROM ItemTable t JOIN ItemAttributesTable at ON t.ItemID = at.ItemID
                  JOIN AttributeTypesTable tt ON at.attributeID = tt.attributeID
) x
PIVOT
(
 MAX(attributeValue) FOR attributeName IN ([Price], [Weight], [Diameter])
 ) p

SELECT *
FROM NewTable
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cc4c/1/0)

OR

If you have an unknown number of columns(attributeName) to transformation, then you can use a dynamic PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(attributeName)
                      FROM AttributeTypesTable
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

IF OBJECT_ID('NewTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE NewTable                      
SET @query = 'SELECT ItemID, ItemName, FruitOrVeggie, Color, ' + @cols + 
             'INTO NewTable FROM 
             (
              SELECT t.ItemID, t.ItemName, t.FruitOrVeggie, Color, attributeName, attributeValue
              FROM ItemTable t JOIN ItemAttributesTable at ON t.ItemID = at.ItemID
                               JOIN AttributeTypesTable tt ON at.attributeID = tt.attributeID
              ) x
              PIVOT
              (
               MAX(attributeValue) FOR attributeName IN (' + @cols + ')
               ) p '

EXEC(@query)

SELECT *
FROM NewTable
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bb54/2/0)

Comment: This does the trick, thank you kindly!  I knew there must be some way to go about this and PIVOT seems to be just the thing.  I also want to thank you for the SQLFiddle examples and the clarification/comments in your answer - thanks for going above and beyond, it is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO NEW TABLE (itemID, itemName, fruitOrVeggie, Color, Price, Weight, Diameter)
SELECT IT.itemID, IT.itemName, IT.fruitOrVeggie, IT.Color, Price.attributeValue, Weight.attributeValue, Diameter.attributeValue
FROM ItemTable IT
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT itemId, attributeValue
        FROM ItemAttributesTable
        WHERE attributeID = 1
    ) AS Price
ON Price.itemID = IT.itemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT itemId, attributeValue
        FROM ItemAttributesTable
        WHERE attributeID = 2
    ) AS Weight
ON Weight.itemID = IT.itemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT itemId, attributeValue
        FROM ItemAttributesTable
        WHERE attributeID = 3
    ) AS Diameter
ON Diameter.itemID = IT.itemID
```

The insert syntax can vary based on the particular SQL implementation that you are using. I would recommend trying the Select portion and see if the rows returned match what you want the rows in the newTable to look like before running the insert.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to pull the attribute names from the table rather than having to hard code them in (as you did here.)  I'll give it a try though, it'd at least be a good start.

Comment: No such luck - I end up with empty values for all the Price, Weight, and Diameter columns.  On the plus side, the stuff from "IT" fills in properly.  How exactly are the Price.attributeValue, Weight.attributeValue, Diameter.attributeValue in the 2nd line supposed to work, because I think this is where the problem is (although I could be wrong.)